# Dealing with c++ libraries not catering for your compiler or IDE

Tags: c++, c++builder, firemonkey, bulletphysics

I'm trying to use Bullet physics (along with either ODE or Newton depending on which one I can get working) inside my multi device firemonkey c++ application. The problem that I keep running into, however, is that these libraries don't seem to cater for C++ builder. They each register their own custom types through conditional defines. For example, they'll use __int64 when detecting MSVC or long long with ming or gcc to type their own big ints. These types are not set within C++ builder because c++ builder doesn't set any environment defines that the libraries check for so the build fails.

I'm no pro with c++, so I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong here. What is the best way to handle this kind of situation?

As a side note, I'm including the source files in the project so that it will build the physics library with any of the platforms I decide to build with so I'm not using anything prebuilt.

Comment: You'd better remove "best way" as you solicit opinionated answers. Back to the topic, you'd have to patch libraries and consider submitting those patches. You might get by supplying defines for missing types using available ones as extra CXXFLAGS.

Comment: C++ builder is unfortunately hopelessly beyond current c++ standards.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I thought so as well, but apparently it is [not quite the case](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/C%2B%2B11_Language_Features_Compliance_Status). Searching suggests that [64bit version is based on clang](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Clang-based_C%2B%2B_Compilers).

Comment: Yeah SO warned me based on my title that this question could be deleted, but honestly, I'd take anything I could get right now. I did try updating the defines so that it didnt check for the compiler, it just used whatever was being defined when it detecting ming or gcc. But I was hoping there would be a cleaner way to go about it.

Comment: You don't mention what version of C++Builder you are using. Honestly, the newer, clang based compiler is *much* better. It support the C++ standard better, and is much more likely to be supported by third party libraries as clang is also Apple's default compiler.

Comment: I'm on an AppMethod subscription so its XE 8 at the moment. The good news is that Bullet builds for android just fine. I've given up trying to build for win32 since I think that still uses their old borland compiler and its a disaster. Win64 gets pretty far with Bullet but then I get a bizarre error about '_infinite' being an unreferenced external. So thats where I'm stuck at the moment.